# Delete option in Quick Notes of OneNote in my Lumia 525 is invisible

Tags: nokia-lumia-525, onenote

I tried to remove a Quick Note from OneNote in my Lumia 525 Windows Phone by long pressing a Quick Note and I found two options. One is Pin to start and another one is Delete. But that delete option is invisible so I was not able to delete a Quick Note. I tried marking and deleting but at that time also delete option is invisible. Is there any alternative way to delete a Quick Note? Does it is an issue with my mobile or with Windows 8.1 OS? See the screen shot for clear understanding.

[image]

Comment: I have seen this couple of times, the best way to delete this is to go to OneDrive.com on PC and try deleting the individual notes.

Comment: Switched off your mobile data and wifi and then try. It gives option to delete one note

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. I have experienced it before, until I found that you just have to wait. Turn your data connection on (in my case, wifi) and wait for a couple of seconds until the app synchronises. Then, the delete option will become available. Try it.

[image: the screenshot of options before app is completely synced]

[image: the screenshot after app is completely synced]

So, as I said, you just have to wait depending on your data or wifi speed. I had to wait about 23seconds. Patience is the key.

Comment: Notice the screenshot. The OP *is* on Wi-Fi. I have also experienced this problem with full LTE service, and with the app synced completely.

Comment: Notice the screenshots. It should clarify your doubt. Patience is the key.

Answer (score 0):

The Quick Notes section is not an actual notebook but a section for the notes just on your phones which don't get synced. Basically your local default note storage. Therefore you can't delete it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think Sathiya Kumar is wanting how to delete a note *within* Quick Notes, not the entire Quick Notes section...

Comment: Good point. I will delete my answer if Pawans answer should be the accepted.